# Add new node pool to GKE cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running single-node GKE cluster with configuration of 4vCPU & 16 GB Memory. Now i am planning to add one more node pool 1 vCPU and 3.75 GB of RAM.

Right now on a single node, I am running load like Elasticsearch, Redis, Rabbitmq with stateful sets having disk attach.

I have not added any affinity & anti-affinity in Pod configuration. If i will be adding new node may possible some of pods schedule to new node. While i am only planning to run stateless pods on new pods.

Is there any way i can stop scheduling ES, Redis or RabbitMQ on new node without adding affinity or anything don't want to restart(Touch) pod or service. ES, Redis, RabbitMQ should have to stuck on the old node only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`nodeSelector`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) and `kubectl patch` could be the solution.

**Using a new label**

You must fist label the node running the statefull workloads with for instance the following label `statefullnode=true` using the following command:

`kubectl label nodes <node-name> statefullnode=true`

Then you must patch each deployments running on this node using `kubectl patch`:

```
kubectl patch deployments nginx-deployment -p '{"spec": {"template": {"spec": {"nodeSelector": {"statefullnode": "true"}}}}}'
```

---

**Using the node name**

If you don't want to label your node you can simply use the node name as label for the nodeSelector.
For instance if your node's name is **my-gke-node** then run:

```
kubectl patch deployments nginx-deployment -p '{"spec": {"template": {"spec": {"nodeSelector": {"kubernetes.io/hostname": "my-gke-node"}}}}}'
```

---

Run `kubectl get nodes` to get the names of your cluster’s nodes.

Comment: Thanks for writing the answer. I think it's an easy way to update it but due to patch stateful sets pod will restart or not ? As we are updating spec of pod scheduling so.

Comment: For elasticsearch stateful pod not restarted while for redis pod it restarted pod and recreated.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is Taints. "they allow a node to repel a set of pods" ( more details here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/ )

From the link above (assuming node1 is the new node) in your example:

`kubectl taint nodes node1 key=value:NoSchedule` - This means that no pod will be able to schedule onto node1 unless it has a matching toleration. (and your existing pods don't have a matching toleration).

And in one of the new pods you will want to schedule on the new node, you will apply this:

```
tolerations:
- key: "key"
  operator: "Equal"
  value: "value"
  effect: "NoSchedule"
```

Thus, the old pods won't be able to schedule to this new node, and only the new pods, and only if you apply the toleration to them, will be able to schedule on the new node.

Comment: thanks for writing an answer but for taints and toleration I think i have to update spec for all containers.

Comment: @HarshManvar No, you surely need to make changes only to the new pods. I'll edit my previous answer with examples.

Comment: thanks i got it. But is there something possible like i can edit already deployed 3 pods of elastic redis and rabbitmq ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What would you like to edit on the 3 pods of elastic redis and rabbitmq?